# How do I process multiple sentences in one go using the simple CoreNLP server

Tags: stanford-nlp

If I send two sentences (delimited by newline) in the body of a POST request to the [simple CoreNLP server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html), the two sentences get analyzed as one, and the returned list of JSON object contains only one element. What settings do I have to pass to the server, so that each sentences is analyzed separately, and results are returned as a list of two JSON objects, one for each sentence?

[Screenshot of a POST request and the returned JSON array containing only one element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e0Mz.jpg)

Setting the property "ssplit.eonly":"true" does not seem to help either:

[Turning on ssplit.eonly does not help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIrBn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `"ssplit.eolonly": "true"` to your JSON.

Comment: I've modified my question to indicate that adding "ssplit.eonly":"true" does not solve the problem.

Comment: sorry typo, that should be "ssplit.eolonly"